# PySpark split map column into Multiple based on starting value of the Key

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
ID               MPCol
1        [a1 -> 1, b1 -> 2, a12 -> 5, b23 ->2, c12 ->2]
2        [a2 -> 2, b3 -> 3, a15 -> 1, b45 ->1, c54 ->2]
3        [a17 -> 2, b15 -> 1, a88 -> 2, b90 ->8, c98 -> 5]
```

I want something like this

```
ID  MPCol1             MPCol2              MPCol3                     
1  [a1 ->1, a12 -> 5],[b1 -> 2, b23 -> 2],[c12 -> 2]
2  [a2 -> 2,a15 -> 1],[b3 -> 3, b45 -> 1],[c54 -> 2]
3  [a17 -> 2,a88 -> 2],[b15 ->1, b90 -> 8],[c98 -> 5]
```

I want to split the map based on starting letter of key, all keys with a in one and all keys with b in another and similarly with c

My approach

```
df.withColumn("MPCOL")
  .select($"MPCOL", explode($"A1"))
  .groupBy("MPCOL")
  .pivot("key")
  .agg(first("value")).show()
```

Comment: what is the data type of the input field? a `MapType()` column will look like `{a -> 1, b -> 2}`. an `ArrayType(MapType())` will look like `[{a -> 1, b -> 2}]`.

Comment: You cannot have several maps in one cell. Do you want to have several columns with one map each? What is the reason why you want such structure, i.e. why the current one is not performing well enough for you?

Comment: @ZygD, Yes Several column with one map  will work. My Map col is currently not sorted and I want to split it based on starting characters. I have edited the question as per what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need Scala solution (from how your input looks like), you can use udf() to do the grouping:

```
val df = Seq(
  Map("a1" -> 1, "b1" -> 2, "a12" -> 5, "b23" -> 2, "c12" -> 2),
  Map("a2" -> 2, "b3" -> 3, "a15" -> 1, "b45" -> 1, "c54" -> 2),
  Map("a17" -> 2, "b15" -> 1, "a88" -> 2, "b90" -> 8, "c98" -> 5),
).toDF("MPCol")
  .select((monotonically_increasing_id() + lit(1)).as("ID"), $"*")

val group = udf((_: Map[String, Int]).groupBy(_._1.substring(0, 1)))
val keys = df.select(explode($"MPCol")).select($"key".substr(0, 1)).distinct().map(_.getString(0)).collect
val cols = keys.sorted.zipWithIndex.map(k => $"group".getItem(k._1).as(s"MPCol${k._2 + 1}")).prepended($"ID")

df.show(false)
df.withColumn("group", group($"MPCol")).select(cols: _*).show(false)
```

For pyspark, it's best to avoid using udf() since they can be slow:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [[{"a1": 1, "b1": 2, "a12": 5, "b23": 2, "c12": 2}],
     [{"a2": 2, "b3": 3, "a15": 1, "b45": 1, "c54": 2}],
     [{"a17": 2, "b15": 1, "a88": 2, "b90": 8, "c98": 5}],
     ], ["MPCol"]
).select((F.monotonically_increasing_id() + F.lit(1)).alias('ID'), "*")

df2 = df.select('ID', F.explode('MPCol'), F.col('key').substr(0, 1).alias('first_char'))

name_map = df2.select('first_char').distinct().sort('first_char').withColumn(
    'col_name', F.concat(F.lit('MPCol'), F.monotonically_increasing_id() + F.lit(1))
).toPandas()

df.show(truncate=False)
(
    df2.replace(name_map['first_char'].tolist(), name_map['col_name'].tolist())
    .groupby('ID', 'first_char')
    .agg(F.map_from_arrays(F.collect_list('key'), F.collect_list('value')).alias('collected'))
    .groupby('ID')
    .pivot('first_char')
    .agg(F.first('collected'))
    .show(truncate=False)
)
```

Comment: What's F ? you missed that line I think

Comment: @bzu I forgot to include the ID column, the solutions seems to work but can you edit it to include the ID column as well?

Comment: @Zircoz It's the standard import used for pyspark functions: `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`

Comment: @AbhishekPatil I added the IDs. For pyspark I removed UDF so the solution is more like you originally had in mind.